# Asp.net access controls of user control from aspx page

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have a user control and it has a method which is executed when button on aspx page is clicked, I m passing two ids of the user control in the method, Now i want to get the values of the textbox in the user control but unfortunately it is not recognizing textbox I have coded :-

```
 //Method to copy values from one control into another
        public void copyInfo(Control ctrl1, Control ctrl2) {  
            List<string> vals = new List<string>();
            foreach (Control c in ctrl1.Controls)
            {
                if (c is TextBox)
                {    
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(((TextBox)c).Text)) { }
                    else {
                   //values from textbox
                        vals.Add(((TextBox)c).Text);
                    }
                }

                              .............
                                ..........
                                  ......
```

how can i get the textbox control and there values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a public property on your UserControl such as:

```
public string SomeTextboxValue
{
  get
  {
    return SomeTextBox.Text;
  }

  set
  {
    SomeTextBox.Text = value;
  }
}
```

Then you need to cast your controls into their actual types rather than the generic `Control` class:

```
SomeControl someControl1 = (SomeControl)ctrl1;
SomeControl someControl2 = (SomeControl)ctrl2;
someControl1.SomeTextboxValue = someControl2.SomeTextboxValue;
```

Or the other way around depending on which your from and dest are in the copy.

### Update to discuss dynamic controls

If your controls are being dynamically created and you can't find it on postback its probably because you haven't recreated the controls on postback. I have found this article series to be very interesting when trying to understand how to work with and process data from dynamic controls:

- https://web.archive.org/web/20211020150032/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/090308-1.aspx

That link is to part three but its where the important part is which covers your scenario:

> **Creating the Custom Client Attribute UI and Loading the Client's
>   Current Values from the Database**
>
> When programmatically adding Web controls to an ASP.NET page it is
>   essential that the controls are added to the page **on each and every
>   page visit**. This includes the first page visit and *all* subsequent
>   postbacks.

Comment: SomeTextBox what is this for? Please can u tell me how to use your code and i m dynamically creating and adding textbox.

Comment: Ah ok you should update your question to make it clear that its a dynamic textbox as that changes the issue.

Comment: Thanks rtpHarry ur link helped me.