# Retrieve WebUserControl's repeater data after the rendering of the control in page ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I have a WebUserControl with a repeater inside it. 
I rendered the Control in a dialog inside a div in the main page using RenderControl() in this way:

```
Dim sb As New StringBuilder(512)
Dim sw As New StringWriter(sb)
Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
Dim cTest As wucTest = Nothing

cTest = CType(New UserControl().LoadControl("~/Controls/wucTest.ascx"), wucTest)
cTest.LoadControlTest()
cTest.RenderControl(hw)
sw.Flush()
cReturnValue = sw.ToString()
```

Now i have my dialog open with my Control inside it, and i need to access to the various rows of the repeater depending on the different cases. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes it's possible. Do you want to access to your repeater control on the server side? If so, have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6679268/2835243).

Comment: Not from the server side. I hoped it was possible with jQuery...

Comment: Oh yes it is. When an user control is added to an aspx page, see it as the user control's controls were added to the page. So you can access to the repeater control as if it was part of your aspx page, because it kind of is. Although, be aware where you try to access your repeater rows. If you do it on document load, it may not work since your user control may not have been added to the page since you add it programmatically I see.